# Creating a custom interpreter in Bash

Tags: bash, interpreter

I'm experimenting with something.

I've written a set of functions in Bash and I want to execute my scripts like this:

```
$ test.sh arg1 arg2
```

`test.sh` would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env foo

echo "It works: $1 $2"
```

`/usr/bin/foo` looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec /usr/libexec/foo/runner "$@"
```

And `/usr/libexec/foo/runner` would look something like this:

```
# This file would set error handling and traps.
. /usr/libexec/foo/bootstrap.sh
```

I know this isn't right, particularly because nothing really happens when I run `test.sh`!
How can I fix this so that I can use `foo` as my interpretter for my scripts?

Comment: Most operating systems do not allow a shell script to be the interpreter in a shebang for security reasons.

Comment: About shebang nesting: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#interpreter-script.